# MS Test integration tests with SQL Server CE and EF 6 migrations

Tags: entity-framework-6, sql-server-ce, mstest, entity-framework-migrations

I want to use SQL Server CE 4, together with EF 6 migrations, for database operations in my integration tests.

The id´s of the entities are Guid´s and some of them are generated by server by using:

```
.HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
```

The others use

```
.HasKey(x => x.Id);
```

which are also a Guid but something that is set on the entity before persisting.

However i get following exception when my context calls:
    context.saveChanges();

**Exception:**

```
{"Server-generated keys are only supported for identity columns. The column 'Id' has type 'SqlServerCe.uniqueidentifier', which is not a valid type for an identity column."}
```

Is this because sql server ce can´t generate id´s ?

I use same context for SQL Server and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, due to limitations in the SQL Server Compact engine, it is not possible to get the generated id value back from the engine.

It is possible to set a default

```
newid()
```

But the engine offers no way of getting the assigned Guid value after saving (unlike with int values, where you can use @@IDENTITY)